# Entity Framework code first approach - Visual Studio not connecting to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I won't be able to create database using code first approach. Getting error when trying to update-database after adding migrations successfully:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll
> from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local
> Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly
> installed.)

Model folder contains simple class:

```cs
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Dbcontext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Movie> movies { get; set; }
    
    public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```cs
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    // GET: Movies
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Order of commands in which they are executed:

```
PM> add-migrations InitialModel.
PM> update-database -Verbose.
```

Please help !

Comment: Do you have permissions?  Can you machine reach the SQL server?

Comment: Yes. I have administrator rights and SQLSERVER is working fine basically my machine able to connect properly to sql server. I have a question to ask @brad my sql server agent service is not running what do you thing about that?  This error is because of that?

Comment: Unless you are trying to schedule jobs I dont think Agent is required (but I dont know everything your code is doing but from description should not be required).  The error says Verify local DB Runtime is running that is different from Agent (I believe)

Comment: Okay! I am getting this specific error in package manager console in visual studio 2015 community edition.

Comment: package manager?  Is this an SSIS package then?

Comment: No i haven't install any package. In entity framework code first approach you make c# classes first than run few commands on package manger console (it's available in visual studio) to create database. So i am getting this error on update-database command after successfully running the migrations.

Comment: Please provide the code you are running that gets you the error.

Comment: It's not the code that i am having trouble with, It's just a command that is not executing.

Comment: I understand that, but maybe the command is not correct, or the order, or something else in the code could be the issue.  Without seeing it just an error message is not enough to help.

Comment: There you go @brad i have updated my post !